# Cash on delivery payment method should visible only for some zip codes/pin codes

Tags: shipping-address, cash-on-delivery

we are using "Cash On Delivery" Payment method in magento 1.9.0

we support cash on delivery to only some zip/pin codes locations.

means we will accept cash only from some zip codes [means locations].

under "checkout" in "shipping address", customer will type his/her "zip code" .

using that zip code we have to validation.

means if we deliver the product to that zip code, than "COD" payment method should visible under "payment method"

otherwise "COD" should not visible.

if someone is unclear with above question , please refer following link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439761/how-to-restrict-default-cod-in-magento-to-certain-zip-codes-only

this is the question.

can anyone explain in detail about above solution....

or

also here in following link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248124/restrict-default-cash-on-delivery-for-some-zip-pin-codes-in-magento-1-9-0/29259050#29259050

there is an option to enter list of zip codes that are restricted. but we need a solution for list of zip codes that allowed.

Comment: i got an answer in stackoverflow  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299718/cash-on-delivery-payment-method-should-visible-only-for-some-zip-codes-pin-codes/29360908#29360908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already created a table to store COD available pin codes, get customer's pin-code with below code and match with your table pin -code values.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
//or
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
```

Now you need to put a condition to show COD method. Update below file...

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml`

Find code near line 43

```
if(($_method->getCode() == "cashondelivery") && --Your custom condition--)
```

Comment: i will check and inform  you soon.....